# php zip library sub folders

Tags: php, zip

im using the php zip command like this:

```
$zipped = create_zip($files,"box.zip");
```

and the $files is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ../../folder1/file1.doc
    [1] => ../../folder2/file2.doc
    [2] => ../../folder3/file3.pdf
    [3] => ../../folder4/file4.cvs

)
```

When the file created it flow the original folder structure.
but i have it serve files without sub folder schema!mean like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => file1.doc
    [1] => file2.doc
    [2] => file3.pdf
    [3] => file4.cvs

)
```

is there any way for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the second parameter of [`ZipArchive::addFile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) when adding content. It is called `$localname` and used to set the filename and path inside the archive.

In your case it should look like:

```
$zip->addFile('path/to/file', basename('path/to/file'));
```